Adding a Tag Key for a metric in Datadog's Confluent Cloud Integration
Datadog's integration with Confluent Cloud includes a predefined set of metrics and tags. Is there a way to add an additional tag key for a specific metric, such as confluent_cloud.connect.received_records, to include the topic as one of the TAG KEY? What would be the most effective method to achieve this?
